# Autoremove command removed too many packages

Tags: apt, uninstall

I was uninstalling some items from Xubuntu 14.04 and APT suggested I use `autoremove`, so I did, and when I logged in after rebooting everything important is gone. Even my Chrome browser is uninstalled.

What should I do?

Here is my history log

```
Start-Date: 2014-10-23  17:34:08
Commandline: apt-get purge wine*
Purge: gconf-service:i386 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2), inkscape:i386 (0.48.4-3ubuntu2), xubuntu-default-settings:i386 (14.04.5), pidgin-libnotify:i386 (0.14-9ubuntu2), python-ldb:i386 (1.1.16-1), python-pycurl:i386 (7.19.3-0ubuntu3), abiword-plugin-mathview:i386 (3.0.0-4ubuntu1.1), python3-pycurl:i386 (7.19.3-0ubuntu3), libldb1:i386 (1.1.16-1), gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad:i386 (0.10.23-7.2ubuntu1), pidgin:i386 (2.10.9-0ubuntu3.1), gtk-theme-config:i386 (1.0-1), libgnomevfs2-common:i386 (2.24.4-1ubuntu6), software-properties-gtk:i386 (0.92.37.1), libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 (1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1), chromium-browser-l10n:i386 (37.0.2062.120-0ubuntu0.14.04.1~pkg1049), chromium-browser:i386 (37.0.2062.120-0ubuntu0.14.04.1~pkg1049), libabiword-3.0:i386 (3.0.0-4ubuntu1.1), libcurl3:i386 (7.35.0-1ubuntu2.1), python3-software-properties:i386 (0.92.37.1), kerneloops-daemon:i386 (0.12+git20090217-3ubuntu8), libraptor2-0:i386 (2.0.13-1), samba:i386 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), samba-common-bin:i386 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), winbind:i386 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), wine-gecko2.21:i386 (2.21-0ubuntu1), xchat-common:i386 (2.8.8-7.1ubuntu5), wine-mono0.0.8:i386 (0.0.8-0ubuntu1), libgnomevfs2-0:i386 (2.24.4-1ubuntu6), libgnomevfs2-extra:i386 (2.24.4-1ubuntu6), xchat-indicator:i386 (0.3.11-0ubuntu4), python-samba:i386 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), system-config-printer-udev:i386 (1.4.3+20140219-0ubuntu2.2), libkdc2-heimdal:i386 (1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1), samba-vfs-modules:i386 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), librdf0:i386 (1.0.17-1), samba-dsdb-modules:i386 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), libsmbclient:i386 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), libhdb9-heimdal:i386 (1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1), wine1.6-i386:i386 (1.6.2-0ubuntu4), libslv2-9:i386 (0.6.6+dfsg1-2), libldap-2.4-2:i386 (2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8), network-manager-gnome:i386 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.3), gconf-service-backend:i386 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2), winetricks:i386 (0.0+20140302-0ubuntu2), libcurl3-gnutls:i386 (7.35.0-1ubuntu2.1), system-config-printer-common:i386 (1.4.3+20140219-0ubuntu2.2), vlc-plugin-notify:i386 (2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1), abiword:i386 (3.0.0-4ubuntu1.1), samba-libs:i386 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), python-cupshelpers:i386 (1.4.3+20140219-0ubuntu2.2), libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 (1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1), xubuntu-desktop:i386 (2.180), whoopsie:i386 (0.2.24.6), smbclient:i386 (4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.3), vlc:i386 (2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1), wine1.6:i386 (1.6.2-0ubuntu4), libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 (1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1), system-config-printer-gnome:i386 (1.4.3+20140219-0ubuntu2.2), gconf2:i386 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2), python-smbc:i386 (1.0.14.1-0ubuntu2), software-properties-common:i386 (0.92.37.1), software-center:i386 (13.10-0ubuntu4.1), pepperflashplugin-nonfree:i386 (1.3ubuntu1), flashplugin-installer:i386 (11.2.202.411ubuntu0.14.04.1), vlc-plugin-pulse:i386 (2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1), librasqal3:i386 (0.9.32-1), xchat:i386 (2.8.8-7.1ubuntu5), gvfs-backends:i386 (1.20.1-1ubuntu1), libwind0-heimdal:i386 (1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1), abiword-plugin-grammar:i386 (3.0.0-4ubuntu1.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386 (1.2.4-1~ubuntu1), libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 (1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1), apt-transport-https:i386 (1.0.1ubuntu2.5), python-gconf:i386 (2.28.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2), vlc-nox:i386 (2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1)
End-Date: 2014-10-23  17:36:34

Start-Date: 2014-10-23  17:37:35
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Remove: libopenal1:i386 (1.14-4ubuntu1), libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:i386 (1.2.4-1~ubuntu1), liblua5.2-0:i386 (5.2.3-1), tsconf:i386 (1.0-12), libtar0:i386 (1.2.20-3ubuntu0.1), libspandsp2:i386 (0.0.6~pre21-2), liblivemedia23:i386 (2014.01.13-1), libopencv-contrib2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), libva-x11-1:i386 (1.3.0-2), libzvbi0:i386 (0.2.35-2), libbluray1:i386 (0.5.0-1), libzvbi-common:i386 (0.2.35-2), libenca0:i386 (1.15-2), libxcb-randr0:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1), libwildmidi1:i386 (0.2.3.4-2.1ubuntu3), libgtkglext1:i386 (1.2.0-3.1fakesync3), unixodbc:i386 (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5), libdca0:i386 (0.0.5-6ubuntu1), libproxy-tools:i386 (0.4.11-0ubuntu4), libmpg123-0:i386 (1.16.0-1ubuntu1), libopencv-objdetect2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), libopencv-core2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), libodbc1:i386 (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5), libflite1:i386 (1.4-release-8), libdvbpsi8:i386 (1.0.0-3), libbasicusageenvironment0:i386 (2014.01.13-1), libfaad2:i386 (2.7-8), libopencv-calib3d2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), p7zip:i386 (9.20.1~dfsg.1-4), libofa0:i386 (0.9.3-5ubuntu1), libssh2-1:i386 (1.4.3-2), libosmesa6:i386 (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1), fonts-wqy-microhei:i386 (0.2.0-beta-2), libvlc5:i386 (2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1), libdirectfb-1.2-9:i386 (1.2.10.0-5), libmagick++5:i386 (6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3), ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 (2.1.3-4), libaacs0:i386 (0.7.0-1), libgroupsock1:i386 (2014.01.13-1), libdc1394-22:i386 (2.2.1-2ubuntu2), libopencv-legacy2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), libkate1:i386 (0.4.1-1ubuntu1), tdb-tools:i386 (1.2.12-1), libcdaudio1:i386 (0.99.12p2-13), libfreerdp1:i386 (1.0.2-2ubuntu1), libpostproc52:i386 (0.git20120821-4), libhogweed2:i386 (2.7.1-1), libvo-aacenc0:i386 (0.1.3-1), odbcinst1debian2:i386 (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5), libsidplay2:i386 (2.1.1-14), libmms0:i386 (0.6.2-3ubuntu2), icoutils:i386 (0.31.0-2), libts-0.0-0:i386 (1.0-12), libtbb2:i386 (4.2~20130725-1.1ubuntu1), libopenal-data:i386 (1.14-4ubuntu1), libopencv-ml2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), libopencv-features2d2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), libwildmidi-config:i386 (0.2.3.4-2.1ubuntu3), libgnutls28:i386 (3.2.11-2ubuntu1), libopencv-video2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), perlmagick:i386 (6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3), libxcb-keysyms1:i386 (0.3.9-1ubuntu1), libaio1:i386 (0.3.109-4), gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers:i386 (1.2.4-1~ubuntu1), libresid-builder0c2a:i386 (2.1.1-14), liblircclient0:i386 (0.9.0-0ubuntu5), libsbc1:i386 (1.1-2ubuntu2), libopencv-imgproc2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), libvcdinfo0:i386 (0.7.24+dfsg-0.1ubuntu2), libmatroska6:i386 (1.4.1-2), ttf-wqy-microhei:i386 (0.2.0-beta-2), libgc1c2:i386 (7.2d-5ubuntu2), libupnp6:i386 (1.6.17-1.2), libass4:i386 (0.10.1-3ubuntu1), libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0:i386 (0.10.23-7.2ubuntu1), libgsl0ldbl:i386 (1.16+dfsg-1ubuntu1), libusageenvironment1:i386 (2014.01.13-1), libopencv-highgui2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), libgif4:i386 (4.1.6-11), libmimic0:i386 (1.0.4-2.1ubuntu1), libcapi20-3:i386 (3.25+dfsg1-3.3ubuntu2), libxcb-xv0:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1), libebml4:i386 (1.3.0-2), gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad:i386 (1.2.4-1~ubuntu1), python-dnspython:i386 (1.11.1-1build1), libcddb2:i386 (1.3.2-4fakesync2), gnome-exe-thumbnailer:i386 (0.9.3-0ubuntu1), libswscale2:i386 (9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), libzbar0:i386 (0.10+doc-9build1), libopencv-flann2.4:i386 (2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1), libdirac-encoder0:i386 (1.0.2-6ubuntu1), libiso9660-8:i386 (0.83-4.1ubuntu1), libvlccore7:i386 (2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1), libvo-amrwbenc0:i386 (0.1.3-1), libmpcdec6:i386 (0.1~r459-1ubuntu3), libmodplug1:i386 (0.8.8.4-4.1), odbcinst:i386 (2.2.14p2-5ubuntu5), attr:i386 (2.4.47-1ubuntu1), libxcb-composite0:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1), libcrystalhd3:i386 (0.0~git20110715.fdd2f19-9ubuntu1), fonts-horai-umefont:i386 (460-1), libgme0:i386 (0.5.5-2), libsrtp0:i386 (1.4.5~20130609~dfsg-1), vlc-data:i386 (2.1.4+git20141006+r54582+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1)
End-Date: 2014-10-23  17:38:49
```

Comment: Try `apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Thanks Muru, My desktop is kind of back now..but i don't know what are the other things i have removed accidentally. before those two commands while i was trying to remove wine i also used this following commands sudo rm -rf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts and fc-cache -rv

Comment: @Sneetsher since we were the only two participants, I did get a notification, but forgot about it. :/ Thanks for reminding me. :)

Answer (score 6):

`apt-get remove wine*` does not do what you think it will do. It treats `wine*` as a regular expression, and so removes all packages *containing* `win`. Here's a list of packages you removed (scripted out from the log of both commands): http://paste.ubuntu.com/8716702/

At first glance, I'd say you should install `xubuntu-desktop`, which will bring a lot of your desktop back. At second glance, the following packages might also be needed, since these are not part of the default installation (IIRC), so must have been installed by you:

```
chromium-browser inkscape p7zip vlc xchat
```

---

```
sudo rm -rf  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts 
fc-cache -rv
```

These should remove the fonts installed by `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package, but it would be simpler to remove it instead:

```
sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: most of them i installed as and when needed or/and just for curiosity. Thanks for the help.