# Attempting to remove old kernels in /boot led to broken wlan, display resolution on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management, kernel

Following the steps here: [What is the safest way to clean up /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition) to free some space in `/boot` I was lazy. So instead of deleting every file seperately with `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-VERSION`, I typed `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3*` after some time I realized that this maybe was a huge mistake and i stopped it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

After a reboot I find my system with no usb connectivity, no wlan, no sound and the lowest possible display resolution. Can someone explain what I have done wrong and/or how I can fix this?

Comment: In `grub`, try `Advanced Boot`, and select the oldest kernel and see if it boots correctly. Then, update to the newest kernel.

Comment: See also [Autoremove command removed too many packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540581/autoremove-command-removed-too-many-packages)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In related posts I found [I think I accidentally removed the current linux kernel when trying to free up space in /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561251/i-th) where i found `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image` command. After using google to find some necessary linux-images for Ubuntu 14.04. I reinstalled

```
linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-105-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-105-generic
```

and booted into GRUB (by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> after bios screen). Choosing `Advanced...` I booted one of the kernel versions above which had all the missing drivers installed. After removing all the installed linux-image-4.. and a `sudo update-grub` my system is booting by default to version 3.x.

Right now I am very happy that my system is back and running!

---

But there is another little thing now. I tried to run `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3*` before I realized that this is a huge pile of data. After some minutes my /boot/ directory was full. 
Now after `dpkg --list 'linux-image*'` I see a long list with all `linux-image-3*` files. Like this:

```
un  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic    <none>    <none>    (no description available)
```

How can I remove them?

Comment: Start removing them. Nice job. I thought you would've learned to be careful with wildcards the first time.